# establish bluetooth piconet connection between server and two clients using c on linux platform?

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth

I want to establish Bluetooth network where one server can communicate to two clients (ie piconet) using C programm on linux platform, rfcomm based communication.

Can any one please share your guidance or sample source code if have.

I newbie to the bluetooth technology, have not found any useful info or code from internet source so far. so please.

Thank you
Basu

Answer (score 0):

Linux runs open source [BlueZ Bluetooth Stack](http://www.bluez.org/), which works quite well (unless you need Bluetooth Low Energy). You can check out this tutorial: http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html

PS. Mind the GPL license when using `#include` like in those examples.

Edit:
As for creating piconet specifically, I'm afraid I don't have any snippets. However, after quick search, I would look into using bluez library to open not one but many RFCOMM sockets. So you can listen to and accept multiple connections.

Comment: Hi Rafal, Thanks for the reply, i saw this tutorial before, didnt given anything about one to multipoint(piconet) connection programming. Please share any which related to one (1server)-to-multipoint (many clients upto 2-7) if you have.

Comment: @sagar I updated my answer but I'm afraid I don't have code to share.